# Oracle: Script to verify that objects belong to their tablespaces

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have 2 tablespaces, one to store tables and other on to store indexes. I created a script that can be run in any of my schemas and it will move objects (tables or indexes) to their respective tablespaces.

However, I am failing to come up with a script that will verify that objects have been moved to the correct tablespaces (meaning tables have been moved to the table tablespace, and indexes have been moved to the index tablespace).

Any thoughts?

Comment: How would a human (e.g. you) know if "objects have been moved to the correct tablespaces"? Once you figure that out, coding it in PL/SQL is trivial.

Comment: `select SEGMENT_NAME OBJECT_NAME, SEGMENT_TYPE OBJECT_TYPE, TABLESPACE_NAME 
from user_segments 
where segment_type in ('INDEX','TABLE');`

I am currently using this script but this is not sufficient because I don't want to look through all records to verify that each object has been moved successfully to its respective tablespace.

Comment: What is wrong with the `user_segments` query you have? Are you saying you want to check the tablespace history for a segment and not just the current tablespace?

Comment: I want a query that will display counts of indexes i have and the count should be the same where tablespace_name is the indexes tablespace.

Comment: It's still not clear what is wrong with what you tried. What result specifically are you looking for and not getting?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the query below to get the information through a spesific schema :

```
select t.table_name, t.tablespace_name as "TS Name For Table",
       i.index_name, i.tablespace_name as "TS Name For Indexes"
  from user_tables t
  join user_indexes i on i.table_name = t.table_name
 order by t.table_name, i.index_name;
```

Comment: I want a query that will display counts of indexes i have and the count should be the same where tablespace_name is the indexes tablespace.